# Has the corpus of Tosafoth been printed in one volume?

Tags: talmud-gemara, jewish-books, text, tosfot

The Talmudic commentary called Tosafoth has been printed together with the Talmud text itself for many centuries. For example, even Maharal testifies (in 1595) to this in [Nesiv Hatorah ch. 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Netivot_Olam,_Netiv_Hatorah.5.2):

> והכל בשביל שלמודם תוס' דבר שהוא הוספה וכי לא היה טוב יותר שיקנה גוף התלמוד קודם, והכל בשביל שנדפסו התוספות אצל הגמרא.
>   ...It is because they were taught Tosafoth, which, as its name attests, is only but an addition. However, would it not have been more fitting for a student to study the very text of the Talmud itself? This is only because the Tosafoth are printed on the same page as the Talmud.

However, I imagine that prior to such printing presses they were copied as a stand alone work. Regardless, as with many books, such as Tosefta, has there been a printing of the Tosafoth as a stand alone book? Besides reference, they could also serve as critical version of the texts.

Although there are many different volumes in print which contain in the title ‘Tosafoth’, I seek only that which is printed in the standard Talmud layout.

Comment: The Tosafos printed with the Gemara is not a single work with a single editor. In some tractates there is even a break in the middle, the first half being from one collection and the second from another. It seems to me that this has precluded a critical edition of Tosafos on the whole of Shas. BTW, Oz VeHadar brings a list of which Tosafos collection was printed in each mesechta in their biography appendex to meseches Brachos.